# Function similar to group_by when groups are not mutually exlcusive

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I would like to create a function in R, similar to `dplyr`'s `group_by` function, that when combined with `summarise` can give summary statistics for a dataset where *group membership is not mutually exclusive*. I.e., observations can belong to multiple groups. One way to think about it might be to consider tags; observations may belong to one or more tags which might overlap.

For example, take R's `esoph` dataset (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/esoph.html) documenting a case-control study of esophageal cancer. Suppose I'm interested in the number and proportion of cancer cases overall and per 'tag', where the tags are: 65+ years old; 80+ gm/day alcohol; 20+ gm/day tobacco; and a 'high risk' group where the previous 3 criteria are met.
Let's transform the dataset to long format (one participant per row) and then add these tags (logical columns) to the dataset:

```
library('dplyr')
data(esoph)
esophlong = bind_rows(esoph %>% .[rep(seq_len(nrow(.)), .$ncases), 1:3] %>% mutate(case=1),
                      esoph %>% .[rep(seq_len(nrow(.)), .$ncontrols), 1:3] %>% mutate(case=0)
            ) %>% 
            mutate(highage=(agegp %in% c('65-74','75+')),
                   highalc=(alcgp %in% c('80-119','120+')),
                   hightob=(tobgp %in% c('20-29','30+')),
                   highrisk=(highage & highalc & hightob)
            )
```

My usual approach is to create a dataset where each observation is duplicated for every tag it belongs to, and then `summarise` this dataset:

```
esophdup = bind_rows(esophlong %>% filter(highage) %>% mutate(tag='age>=65'),
                     esophlong %>% filter(highalc) %>% mutate(tag='alc>=80'),
                     esophlong %>% filter(hightob) %>% mutate(tag='tob>=20'),
                     esophlong %>% filter(highrisk) %>% mutate(tag='high risk'),
                     esophlong %>% filter() %>% mutate(tag='all')
           ) %>%
           mutate(tag=factor(tag, levels = unique(.$tag)))

summary = esophdup %>%
          group_by(tag) %>%
          summarise(n=n(), ncases=sum(case), case.rate=mean(case))
```

This approach is inefficient for large datasets or for a large number of tags and I will often run out of memory to store it.

An alternative is to `summarise` each tag separately and then bind these summary datasets afterwards, as follows:

```
summary.age = esophlong %>%
              filter(highage) %>%
              summarise(n=n(), ncases=sum(case), case.rate=mean(case)) %>%
              mutate(tag='age>=65')

summary.alc = esophlong %>%
              filter(highalc) %>%
              summarise(n=n(), ncases=sum(case), case.rate=mean(case)) %>%
              mutate(tag='alc>=80')

summary.tob = esophlong %>%
              filter(hightob) %>%
              summarise(n=n(), ncases=sum(case), case.rate=mean(case)) %>%
              mutate(tag='tob>=20')

summary.highrisk = esophlong %>%
              filter(highrisk) %>%
              summarise(n=n(), ncases=sum(case), case.rate=mean(case)) %>%
              mutate(tag='high risk')

summary.all = esophlong %>%
              summarise(n=n(), ncases=sum(case), case.rate=mean(case)) %>%
              mutate(tag='all')

summary=bind_rows(summary.age,summary.alc,summary.tob,summary.highrisk,summary.all)
```

This approach is time-consuming and tedious when I have a large number of tags or I want to reuse the tags often for different summary measures throughout a project.

The function I have in mind, say `group_by_tags(data, key, ...)`, which includes an argument to specify the name of the grouping column, should work something like this:

```
summary = esophlong %>% 
          group_by_tags(key='tags',
                        'age>=65'=highage,
                        'alc>=80'=highalc,
                        'tob>=20'=hightob,
                        'high risk'=highrisk,
                        'all ages'=1
          ) %>%
          summarise(n=n(), ncases=sum(case), case.rate=mean(case))
```

with the summary dataset looking like this:

```
> summary
       tags     n ncases case.rate
1   age>=65   273     68 0.2490842
2   alc>=80   301     96 0.3189369
3   tob>=20   278     64 0.2302158
4 high risk    11      5 0.4545455
5       all  1175    200 0.1702128
```

Even better, it could take variables of type "factor" as well as "logical" so that it could summarise, say, each age group individually, the 65+ year olds, and everybody:

```
summaryage = esophlong %>% 
          group_by_tags(key='Age.group',
                        agegp,
                        '65+'=(agegp %in% c('65-74','75+')),
                        'all'=1                 
          ) %>%
          summarise(n=n(), ncases=sum(case), case.rate=mean(case))

>summaryage
  Age.group     n ncases case.rate
1     25-34   117      1 0.0085470
2     35-44   208      9 0.0432692
3     45-54   259     46 0.1776062
4     55-64   318     76 0.2389937
5     65-74   216     55 0.2546296
6       75+    57     13 0.2280702
7       65+   273     68 0.2490842
8       all  1175    200 0.1702128
```

Perhaps it's not possible with `...` and instead you might need to pass a vector/list of column names for the tags.

Any ideas?

EDIT: to be clear, the solution should take tag/group definitions and the required summary statistics as arguments, rather than being built into the function itself. Either as a two-step `data %>% group_by_tags(tags) %>% summarise_tags(stats)` or a one-step `data %>% summary_tags(tags,stats)` process.

Comment: Doesn't `group_by_tags` imply that you would also have data *not* within each? IOW, your summary would have 10 rows: your 5 plus "`! age>=65`", etc.

Comment: @r2evans only if it treated logical variables as factor variables. Though maybe the extension to include factors is a step too far

Comment: `summarize` assumes that the lengths of the grouped rows adds up to the number of rows in the data (which is not the case here), so you'd have to either create your own summarize function or add a class to `dplyr`, such as `"grouped_df_partial"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of any knowledge of tidyverse internals, I avoided trying to create `group_by()`-type function whose output should be passed to `summarise()` and instead made a single function that combines both (similar to other answers but, I hope, more user-friendly and generalisable).

Since `group_by() %>% summarise()` returns the joint summary information for each nested combination of grouping variables, I chose the name `summarise_marginal()` since it will return the marginal summary information for each grouping variable independently.

## Solution that doesn't work with `grouped_df` objects

First, a solution that doesn't work with `grouped_df` classes, but is extended below:

```
summarise_marginal0 <- function(.tbl, .vars, ..., .removeF=FALSE){

  dots <- quos(...)

  .tbl %>% 
    transmute(!!! .vars) %>% 
    map_dfr(
      ~ summarise(group_by(.tbl, 'value'=., add = TRUE), !!! dots) %>%  # piping .tbl %>% group_by() %>% summarise() evaluates in the wrong order for some reason
      filter_at(vars('value'), all_vars(!(.==FALSE & .removeF))) %>%  # to remove rows where a logical group is FALSE.
      mutate_at(vars('value'), as.character)  # standardises 'value' column in case map_dfr tries to convert logical to factor
      , .id='group'
    )
}


mtcars %>% 
  summarise_marginal0(
    vars(cyl, am),
    meanmpg = mean(mpg),
    meanwt = mean(wt)
  )

#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   group value  meanmpg   meanwt
#>   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1   cyl     4 26.66364 2.285727
#> 2   cyl     6 19.74286 3.117143
#> 3   cyl     8 15.10000 3.999214
#> 4    am     0 17.14737 3.768895
#> 5    am     1 24.39231 2.411000
```

Capturing groups with `vars()` (like with `summarise_at()` or `mutate_at()`) neatly separates the groups from the summary functions, and allows new groups to be created on-the-fly:

```
mtcars %>% 
  summarise_marginal0(
    vars(cyl, hp_lt100 = hp<100),
    meanmpg = mean(mpg),
    meanwt = mean(wt)
  )

#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>      group value  meanmpg   meanwt
#>      <chr> <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1      cyl     4 26.66364 2.285727
#> 2      cyl     6 19.74286 3.117143
#> 3      cyl     8 15.10000 3.999214
#> 4 hp_lt100 FALSE 17.45217 3.569652
#> 5 hp_lt100  TRUE 26.83333 2.316667
```

We can use the `.removeF` argument to remove `FALSE` logical values. Useful if you want to summarise certain rows but not their compliment:

```
mtcars %>% 
  summarise_marginal0(
    vars(cyl==6, hp_lt100 = hp<100, hp_lt200 = hp<200),
    meanmpg = mean(mpg),
    meanwt = mean(wt),
    .removeF = TRUE
  )

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>      group value  meanmpg   meanwt
#>      <chr> <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 cyl == 6  TRUE 19.74286 3.117143
#> 2 hp_lt100  TRUE 26.83333 2.316667
#> 3 hp_lt200  TRUE 21.96000 2.911320
```

Notice the how even without explicitly naming the `cyl == 6` group we still get a useful name for it.

## Solution that does work with `grouped_df` objects

`summarise_marginal0()` can be extended to work with `grouped_df` objects returned by `group_by()`:

```
summarise_marginal <- function(.tbl, .vars, ...){

  dots <- quos(...)

  .tbl %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(
      summarised = map(data, ~summarise_marginal0(., .vars, !!! dots))
    ) %>% 
    unnest(summarised) %>%
    purrrlyr::slice_rows(group_vars(.tbl))
}


mtcars %>% 
  group_by(am) %>%
  summarise_marginal(
    vars(cyl, hp_lt100 = hp<100),
    meanmpg = mean(mpg),
    meanwt = mean(wt)
  )

#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#> # Groups:   am [2]
#>       am    group value  meanmpg   meanwt
#>    <dbl>    <chr> <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1     1      cyl     4 28.07500 2.042250
#>  2     1      cyl     6 20.56667 2.755000
#>  3     1      cyl     8 15.40000 3.370000
#>  4     1 hp_lt100 FALSE 20.61429 2.756857
#>  5     1 hp_lt100  TRUE 28.80000 2.007500
#>  6     0      cyl     4 22.90000 2.935000
#>  7     0      cyl     6 19.12500 3.388750
#>  8     0      cyl     8 15.05000 4.104083
#>  9     0 hp_lt100 FALSE 16.06875 3.925250
#> 10     0 hp_lt100  TRUE 22.90000 2.935000
```

In fact, `summarise_marginal()` will work for both grouped and ungrouped `data.frame`s so this function alone is suitable.

This is a useful solution, but given that `group_by()` has uses beyond `summarise()`, for example with `nest()` or `do()`, I think the idea of a `group_by_marginal()` (or `group_by_tag()` or whatever name is best) is worth pursuing.

Some remaining issues:

- The function needs to convert integer, factor and logical columns to character so their values all sit nicely in the same `values` column. This is a slight violation of tidy data principles, though is no different to how `gather()` behaves.
- Assuming a `group_by_marginal()` function is possible, it's output cannot be passed to `mutate()` without resolving the ambiguity of where to place the values from each group. From the example above, which value of `meanmpg` should be given to a row with `cyl==4` and `am==0`? Both `26.66364` (from `cyl==4`) and `17.14737` (from `am==0`) are relevant. (Note there is no ambiguity for `group_by() %>% mutate()` since it will return the joint summary function for `cyl==4 & am==0`). Three possible options for `group_by_marginal() %>% mutate()`:

  1. It should be forbidden.
  2. It should create multiple columns, eg, `meanmpg_cyl` and `meanmpg_am`.
  3. It should replicate rows for each group.
- Speed. I'm certain my implementation of this concept is inefficient and could be improved.

Finally, to demonstrate on the original example problem:

```
bind_rows(
  esoph %>% .[rep(seq_len(nrow(.)), .$ncases), 1:3] %>% mutate(case=1),
  esoph %>% .[rep(seq_len(nrow(.)), .$ncontrols), 1:3] %>% mutate(case=0)
) %>%
summarise_marginal(
  vars(highage = agegp %in% c('65-74','75+'),
       highalc = alcgp %in% c('80-119','120+'),
       hightob = tobgp %in% c('20-29','30+'),
       highrisk = highage & highalc & hightob,
       all = 1),
  n=length(agegp),
  ncases=sum(case),
  case.rate=mean(case),
  .removeF=TRUE
)

#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>      group value     n ncases case.rate
#>      <chr> <chr> <int>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1  highage  TRUE   273     68 0.2490842
#> 2  highalc  TRUE   301     96 0.3189369
#> 3  hightob  TRUE   278     64 0.2302158
#> 4 highrisk  TRUE    11      5 0.4545455
#> 5      all     1  1175    200 0.1702128
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a variation on @eddi's answer. I am taking the definitions of `highage` et al as part of the function's job:

```
library(data.table)
custom_summary = function(DT, tags, stats){
    setDT(DT)
    rows = stack(lapply(tags[-1], function(x) DT[eval(x), which=TRUE]))
    DT[rows$values, eval(stats), by=.(tag = rows$ind)]
}
```

And some example usage:

```
data(esoph)
library(dplyr)
esophlong = bind_rows(esoph %>% .[rep(seq_len(nrow(.)), .$ncases), 1:3] %>% mutate(case=1),
                      esoph %>% .[rep(seq_len(nrow(.)), .$ncontrols), 1:3] %>% mutate(case=0)
            )

custom_summary(
    DT = esophlong, 
    tags = quote(list(
        'age>=65'   = agegp %in% c('65-74','75+'),
        'alc>=80'   = alcgp %in% c('80-119','120+'),
        'tob>=20'   = tobgp %in% c('20-29','30+'),
        'high risk' = eval(substitute(`age>=65` & `alc>=80` & `tob>=20`, as.list(tags))),
        'all ages'  = TRUE
    )),
    stats = quote(list(
        n           = .N, 
        n_cases     = sum(case), 
        case.rate   = mean(case)
    ))
)

         tag    n n_cases case.rate
1:   age>=65  273      68 0.2490842
2:   alc>=80  301      96 0.3189369
3:   tob>=20  278      64 0.2302158
4: high risk   11       5 0.4545455
5:  all ages 1175     200 0.1702128
```

The technique of using `eval` inside `DT[...]` is explained [in the data.table FAQ](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#ok-but-i-dont-know-the-expressions-in-advance.-how-do-i-programatically-pass-them-in).

Comment: Thanks - this is the only function so far where the tags are passed to the function rather than in-built, which is a requirement (I'll make this clearer in the question). It's a bit wordy (eg `quote(list(`...) and I'm not able to use core `dplyr` summary functions (`n`, `nth`, `n_distinct`, etc), but there will be `data.table` equivalents. Given @r2evans's answer (+ see my comment) I think this solution is probably the closest I'll get to what I want without package work.

Comment: Yeah, I cannot figure a way to do it in dplyr without digging into its internals. Data.table is designed to allow for this and even explains this method in its FAQ (I'll add a link in the question). There is an open feature request for dplyr to allow a variable number of returned rows, but I don't think that will fully solve the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

***Not a completely functional answer***, more "WIP" or start for discourse. This should ultimately go in a repo and either an additional package or a PR for [`dplyr`](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr).

One way is to mimic the attributes' structure from a "normally" grouped variable:

```
library(dplyr)
esoph %>% group_by(agegp, alcgp) %>% attributes %>% str
# List of 9
#  $ names             : chr [1:5] "agegp" "alcgp" "tobgp" "ncases" ...
#  $ row.names         : int [1:88] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ class             : chr [1:4] "grouped_df" "tbl_df" "tbl" "data.frame"
#  $ vars              :List of 2
#   ..$ : symbol agegp
#   ..$ : symbol alcgp
#  $ drop              : logi TRUE
#  $ indices           :List of 24
#   ..$ : int [1:4] 0 1 2 3
#   ..$ : int [1:4] 4 5 6 7
#   ..$ : int [1:3] 8 9 10
#   ...........
#  $ group_sizes       : int [1:24] 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 3 4 4 ...
#  $ biggest_group_size: int 4
#  $ labels            :'data.frame':   24 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ agegp: Ord.factor w/ 6 levels "25-34"<"35-44"<..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
#   ..$ alcgp: Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "0-39g/day"<"40-79"<..: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "vars")=List of 2
#   .. ..$ : symbol agegp
#   .. ..$ : symbol alcgp
#   ..- attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
```

We can reproduce this artificially to see if/how it might work:

```
esoph2 <- esoph
syms <- list(as.symbol("agegp65"), as.symbol("alcgp80"))
attr(esoph2, "vars") <- syms
attr(esoph2, "drop") <- TRUE
# 'agegp' and 'aclgp' are ordered factors, for simplicity here just using ints
# `group_by` indices are 0-based
indices <- list(
  which(as.integer(esoph2$agegp) >= 5) - 1,
  which(as.integer(esoph2$alcgp) >= 3) - 1
)
attr(esoph2, "indices") <- indices
attr(esoph2, "group_sizes") <- lengths(indices)
attr(esoph2, "biggest_group_size") <- max(lengths(indices))
df <- data.frame(agegp65 = "agegp >= 65", alcgp80 = "alcgp >= 80", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
attr(df, "vars") <- syms
attr(esoph2, "labels") <- df
class(esoph2) <- c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
```

Which "looks" like a normal grouped data.frame:

```
str(esoph2)
# Classes 'grouped_df', 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':   88 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ agegp    : Ord.factor w/ 6 levels "25-34"<"35-44"<..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ alcgp    : Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "0-39g/day"<"40-79"<..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
#  $ tobgp    : Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "0-9g/day"<"10-19"<..: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
#  $ ncases   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ ncontrols: num  40 10 6 5 27 7 4 7 2 1 ...
#  - attr(*, "vars")=List of 2
#   ..$ : symbol agegp65
#   ..$ : symbol alcgp80
#  - attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
#  - attr(*, "indices")=List of 2
#   ..$ : num  62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 ...
#   ..$ : num  8 9 10 11 12 13 14 23 24 25 ...
#  - attr(*, "group_sizes")= int  26 42
#  - attr(*, "biggest_group_size")= int 42
#  - attr(*, "labels")='data.frame':    1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ agegp65: chr "agegp >= 65"
#   ..$ alcgp80: chr "alcgp >= 80"
#   ..- attr(*, "vars")=List of 2
#   .. ..$ : symbol agegp65
#   .. ..$ : symbol alcgp80
esoph2
# Source: local data frame [88 x 5]
# Groups: agegp65, alcgp80 [2]
#    agegp     alcgp    tobgp ncases ncontrols
#    <ord>     <ord>    <ord>  <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1  25-34 0-39g/day 0-9g/day      0        40
# 2  25-34 0-39g/day    10-19      0        10
# 3  25-34 0-39g/day    20-29      0         6
# 4  25-34 0-39g/day      30+      0         5
# 5  25-34     40-79 0-9g/day      0        27
# 6  25-34     40-79    10-19      0         7
# 7  25-34     40-79    20-29      0         4
# 8  25-34     40-79      30+      0         7
# 9  25-34    80-119 0-9g/day      0         2
# 10 25-34    80-119    10-19      0         1
# # ... with 78 more rows
```

Unfortunately:

```
esoph2 %>% summarize(n = n())
# Error: corrupt 'grouped_df', contains 88 rows, and 68 rows in groups
```

Ergo my comment that `summarize` assumes full coverage; you'd have to modify [`dplyr_summarise_impl`](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/src/summarise.cpp#L105) (in C++), perhaps making a third option to [`summarise_grouped`](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/src/summarise.cpp#L7) and [`summarise_not_grouped`](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/src/summarise.cpp#L70).

Comment: Thanks - So I guess a seamless `dplyr` solution, compatible with `dplyr` conventions, requires some behind-the-scenes package work that I'm not equipped to do. Do you think there will be a desire to add this type of functionality to `dplyr`?

Comment: You can always [ask on GitHub](https://www.github.com/Hadley/dplyr/issues) (and you can always link back to your question here).

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(esophlong)

special.summary = function(dt, vars) {
  rbindlist(lapply(seq_along(vars), function(i) {
      var = vars[[i]]
      if (is.logical(dt[, eval(var)])) {
        dt[eval(var) == TRUE, .(.N, sum(case), mean(case))][, tag := names(vars)[i]][
           , .SD, by = tag] # last step is a lazy version of setcolorder
      } else {
        dt[, .(.N, sum(case), mean(case)), by = .(tag = eval(var))]
      }
    }))
}

special.summary(esophlong, list('age>=65'=quote(highage),
                                'alc>=80'=quote(highalc),
                                'tob>=20'=quote(hightob),
                                'high risk'=quote(highrisk),
                                'all'=quote(TRUE)))

#         tag    N  V2        V3
#1:   age>=65  273  68 0.2490842
#2:   alc>=80  301  96 0.3189369
#3:   tob>=20  278  64 0.2302158
#4: high risk   11   5 0.4545455
#5:       all 1175 200 0.1702128

special.summary(esophlong, list(quote(agegp),
                                '65+'=quote(agegp %in% c('65-74','75+')),
                                'all'=quote(TRUE)))

#     tag    N  V2          V3
#1: 25-34  117   1 0.008547009
#2: 35-44  208   9 0.043269231
#3: 45-54  259  46 0.177606178
#4: 55-64  318  76 0.238993711
#5: 65-74  216  55 0.254629630
#6:   75+   57  13 0.228070175
#7:   65+  273  68 0.249084249
#8:   all 1175 200 0.170212766
```

This can be made more customizable of course, and that's left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (mostly) `dplyr` version:

Given the columns the OP created, the tags could be:

```
tags = list('age>=65'="highage",
            'alc>=80'="highalc",
            'tob>=20'="hightob",
            'high risk'="highrisk",
            'all'=TRUE)
```

But better to create the filtering expressions from the original data as @Frank did:

```
tags1 = list(
  'age>=65'   = ~agegp %in% c('65-74','75+'),
  'alc>=80'   = ~alcgp %in% c('80-119','120+'),
  'tob>=20'   = ~tobgp %in% c('20-29','30+'),
  'high risk' = ~agegp %in% c('65-74','75+') & alcgp %in% c('80-119','120+') & tobgp %in% c('20-29','30+'),
  'all ages'  = TRUE
)
```

Then create a function that uses `lapply` to run the `dplyr` summary on each row of `tags1`:

```
my_summary = function(dat, groups) {
  bind_rows(lapply(1:length(groups), function(i) {
    dat %>% filter_(groups[[i]]) %>% 
      summarise(tag=names(groups)[i],
                n=n(), 
                ncases=sum(case),
                case.rate=mean(case))
  }))
}

my_summary(esophlong, tags1)
```

> ```
>         tag    n ncases case.rate
> 1   age>=65  273     68 0.2490842
> 2   alc>=80  301     96 0.3189369
> 3   tob>=20  278     64 0.2302158
> 4 high risk   11      5 0.4545455
> 5       all 1175    200 0.1702128
> ```

I was hoping to create a simpler way to generate the filtering expressions, but I'm still a bit mystified about how to create complex expressions to use in standard-evaluation versions of `dplyr` functions.

For example, I'd be interested in how to use an approach something like the one below. The `filt` function is intended to create the filtering expression, but the returned expression needs to be unquoted and have a `~` in front of it for `filter_` to interpret it properly. Or maybe there's some gyration with `interp` that's required. Anyway, I'd be interested in how to make this work (or suggestions for a better way) and also how to create a filter with multiple conditions (as in the 'high risk' filter) by combining the individual filters:

```
# Create a filtering expression
filt = function(var, cutoff) {
  paste("as.numeric(gsub('([0-9]{1,3})[-+].*','\\1',", var, ")) >= ", cutoff)
}

# Run the summary function with three different filters plus "all"
my_summary(esophlong, c(mapply(filt, c("agegp","alcgp","tobgp"), c(65,80,20)), 'all'=TRUE))
```

Comment: This is essentially taking the 2nd approach outlined in the question and looping through each tag. It works, but I can't specify the summary statistics explicitly as part of the function call, so it's not as generic as it needs to be.

Comment: I've updated my answer, though it's still not as functional or as elegant as I'd prefer. Please let me know what you think.