# R: I'm trying to group rows by name and year to create a sum output and avg output

Tags: r

I have a large data frame that includes data on the same people over time I want to group each person by years of 2. The result should sum up one column but average the other because a straight average won't work. I can do this in excel however not in R. I included sample data and desired output.

```
Name <- c(rep("Joe",3),rep("Kenny",3))
Age <- c(20,21,22,19,20,21)
Year <- c(rep(c(2010,2011,2012),length.out = 6))
Jumps <- c(10,150,200,300,20,90)
Success <- c(0.5,0.6,0.7,0.4,0.5,0.6)
df <- data.frame(Name,Age,Year,Jumps,Success)
   Name Age Year Jumps Success
1   Joe  20 2010    10     0.5
2   Joe  21 2011   150     0.6
3   Joe  22 2012   200     0.7
4 Kenny  19 2010   300     0.4
5 Kenny  20 2011    20     0.5
6 Kenny  21 2012    90     0.6
```

Desired Output

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Could you show the expected output from excel?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106850/function-similar-to-group-by-when-groups-are-not-mutually-exlcusive and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933058/summarizing-with-overlapping-groups-using-dplyr

Comment: @TarJae I believe I include the table. Let me know if there is a problem.

Comment: Could you provide the formula for Success 59%

Comment: It is just the success rate for each year averaged out. Example: since 50% success of 10 jumps is 5 and 60% of 150 jumps is 90 the result 59% = ((.5*10)+(.6*150))/(10+150)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: Complete solution with success column (removed prior solution):**

Main feature is to use `lead`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(Success = (Success*Jumps),
         Success = Success + lead(Success),
         Age= paste(Age, lead(Age), sep = "-"),
         Jumps = Jumps + lead(Jumps), 
         Year = paste(Year, lead(Year), sep = "-"),
         Success = Success/Jumps) %>% 
  slice(-n())
```

```
 Name  Age   Year      Jumps Success
  <chr> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Joe   20-21 2010-2011   160   0.594
2 Joe   21-22 2011-2012   350   0.657
3 Kenny 19-20 2010-2011   320   0.406
4 Kenny 20-21 2011-2012   110   0.582
```

Comment: Ok cool, I haven't used lead() before so that is interesting. Is it just the Success column that isnt working correctly because the Jumps column seemed to do fine

Comment: If the years are not already in the correct order can we group_by years as well too?

Comment: I will check that!

Comment: I this case we should `arrange` `Year` direct after `group_by(Name)` like: `df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  arrange(Year, .by_group = TRUE) %>% ...`